# Json in Web.Config AppSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to put some mapping config represented in json:

```
[{"Name":"xyz","Ids":["456f782d468","c65b4703"]},{"Name":"abc","Ids":["a95fg567","456sdf564"]}]
```

Is it possible to store a json in appsettings?
I know I can create a custom section in web.config.
But this app may be deployed to Azure Web Apps where appsettings is the only way I see this config can go.

Comment: No. I believe you should store string as appsetting item values. Why not store a custom settings.json file and read from that ?

Comment: I asked a similar question a year ago: [Building a JSON Configuration Section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042795/building-a-json-configuration-section). I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not nicely. The web.config is XML and quotes are not allowed in XML without escaping them to ". Doing that on a JSON still will make it "difficult" to read / maintain. Base64 that serhiyb is one solution, but that will not be maintainable by a person either.

I'd store them as appsettings key/value pairs and then generate the json string at runtime.

If you are 100% the string will never change, then escaping or Base64 is an option.

Comment: The answer below by Mariusz is much nicer and cleaner. I think it should be marked as the accepted response.

Answer (score 0):

With your limitations I would just encode it to `Base64` string and decode it back when you read it from web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `&quot;` instead of quote characters then you can store JSON in app settings or connection strings without issues in the Web.config. E.g.:

```
<add key="ThisIsJson" value="[{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;xyz&quot;}]"/>
```

This doesn't need any special processing either, at least with Json.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I used single quotes to store serialized model in the config, then simply deserialized it after reading it from config.

```
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
        var configFriendlyString = serialized.Replace("\"", "'"); // store it in config file
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectModel>(configFriendlyString);
```

Example of how the serialized object looks in the config:

```
<add key="Categories" value="[{'ID':1,'Name':'All'},{'ID':2,'Name':'Review'}]" />
```

This way it's easily readable and editable. Note that JsonConvert can deserialize it without need of replacing single quotes back with double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

In my web.config, brackets are for using variable like {0} or {1}.
So, I need to escape them with double brackets like that:

```
<add key="ThisIsJson" value="{{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;xyz&quot;}}"/>
```

Hope it will help.